# How to fix 'eslint --init fails'?

Tags: eslint

This is for `Mac, node v10.10.0,npm 6.4.1`

```
eslint --init

? How would you like to use ESLint? To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style
? What type of modules does your project use? JavaScript modules (import/export)
? Which framework does your project use? Vue.js
? Where does your code run? (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)Browser
? How would you like to define a style for your project? Use a popular style guide
? Which style guide do you want to follow? Standard (https://github.com/standard/standard)
? What format do you want your config file to be in? JSON
Checking peerDependencies of eslint-config-plugin:vue/essential,standard@latest
Local ESLint installation not found.
The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:

eslint-plugin-vue@latest eslint-config-plugin:vue/essential,standard@latest error@[object Object] eslint@latest
? Would you like to install them now with npm? Yes
Installing eslint-plugin-vue@latest, eslint-config-plugin:vue/essential,standard@latest, error@[object Object], eslint@latest
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "[object Object]": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/raindwu/.npm/_logs/2019-07-08T16_15_09_665Z-debug.log
```

I expect `'eslint --init' to be successful`, but always encounter the above error

Comment: This should have been resolved in v6.1.0 as per https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11970